# Excel Power Pivot Formula Manipulation

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

When I worked with regular pivot tables, i really enjoyed the ability to manipulate the formula based on cell values to automate what information I'd like to see dynamically.

Regular Pivot Table Example:

Standard Equation: =GETPIVOTDATA("NUM_ROOMS",$C$3,"STAY_DATE",DATE(2015,9,16))

Modified Equation (to automate what info it finds based on cell values): =GETPIVOTDATA(TEXT($A8,""),$C$3,TEXT($A9,""),C$1)

I'm really liking the power of a Power Pivot with multiple sources, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate the Power Pivot formulas in the same manner as I did the regular.

I connected a few Excel flat files containing tables (see below)

[image]

The Power Pivot Formula is a bit different.  It has a different format with respect to your connected tables.  I cannot figure out how to manipulate these formulas in the same way without getting error values.  See screen shot below:

[image: Power Pivot Formula Screen Shot]

Can someone help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=GETPIVOTDATA` formula will only show cells that are already visible in the PivotTable currently. So if you have your PivotTable filtered to 2016 and your GETPIVOTDATA formula asks for 2015 you get nothing.

An alternate approach is to use `=CUBEVALUE` Excel functions as they query the Power Pivot data model directly independent of what's in a PivotTable. An easy way to get started is to go to PivotTable Tools... Analyze ribbon then from the OLAP Tools pulldown choose Convert to Formulas. That will convert the selected PivotTable to CUBEVALUE formulas.

See [Using Excel CUBE Functions with Power Pivot](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2010/06/using-excel-cube-functions-with-powerpivot/) for more details.

You have already discovered that both GETPIVOTDATA and CUBEVALUE use MDX unique member names like `[Measures].[Sum of Rooms]`. The nice thing is that you get intellisense when you start typing CUBEVALUE formulas.

These Excel formulas help you build highly custom formatted reports not possible with the rigid PivotTable formatting limits. Of course if you don't need to customize the format of a report on the Excel sheet more than a PivotTable allows but are needing to code complex analytical calculations that display in the body of a PivotTable I would look at DAX calculated measures that you code inside the Power Pivot window.

Comment: I'm confused.  I converted a test to formulas, but now when I try and order up some data I get 1 every time.  For example, in my table I have a column called "ROOMS" and "STAY DATE".  I tried this as a test.

=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[ROOMS].[ALL]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[STAY_DATE].[01/01/2016]")

It comes up as one, even though there are more than 1 room in "STAY_DATE" 01/01/2016...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelKlein what's your measure (the number). It doesn't look like you're mentioning a measure, so add a new parameter and type "[Measures].[ then intellisense will take over and you can pick the measure in question.

Comment: What if I don't want a calculated measure and just the sum of the rooms for that stay date like a pivot table would do?  The rooms came in the raw data via the table and is not a calculated measure.

Comment: @MichaelKlein "sum of the rooms" is a measure implicitly. If that measure isn't in the list already then build a new PivotTable and add set it up appropriately with the right count and then convert to formulas. From then on that measure will exist in the list and you can use in CUBEVALUE formulas

Comment: That is not the case I'm afraid.  ONLY the fields that I built as measures inside pivot tables are showing up as measures.  This is where it's all breaking down.  So frustrating.  Any way I can send you what I'm talking about?  I'm obviously missing a crucial step here.

Comment: @MichaelKlein I think that's what I'm saying. Build the measure in a PivotTable first. Then you can use it in a CUBEVALUE and delete the PivotTable. Is that an issue?

Comment: Oddly enough, although the measure doesn't display via the intellisense like the calculated measures I built directly, it's still there (really odd no?).  So although it wasn't an option I typed it in any and it returned a value.

Comment: @MichaelKlein maybe the intellisense cache got built before it existed? Not sure. Glad it is working

Comment: Thanks!  Almost.  I need these formulas to be dynamic based on other cells, but dates are being tricky.  Example: =GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of ROOMS]",BOOKINGS_PIV_STLY!$A$4,"[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[YEAR]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[YEAR].&[2017]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[MONTH]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[MONTH].&[Jan]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[STAY_DATE]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[STAY_DATE].&[2017-01-01T00:00:00]").  How do I replace 2017-01-01T00:00:00 with a an Excel cell that points to a particular date?

Comment: My best try so far was breaking the GetPivot to CubeValue with this formula =CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of ROOMS]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[YEAR].&["&A11&"]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[MONTH].&[Jan]","[BOOKINGS RAW DATA].[STAY_DATE].&["&A12&"]") and references A12 as the cell with the date I'm looking for.  Make sense?

Comment: @MichaelKlein instead of A12 try formatting it like TEXT(A12,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"T00:00:00"

Comment: Thanks this worked with the &"T00:00:00" but I'm just trying to understand why I'd have to do this?  In a regular pivot table, if it's formatted as a date in the table data that the pivot table is powered from, we're fine.  With Power Pivots, all of this work just to get the date in this format as a workaround just doesn't make sense.  Is it something with my table data?

Comment: @MichaelKlein that's just the way Power Pivot works. It comes up with a unique name for each member

Comment: @MichaelKlein if I have answered your original question please check the checkmark to mark this answer please.